# chronicle queue serialising throwables

Tags: java, chronicle-queue

Using version 4.5.27
I'm using this code to write a Throwable to a queue and then read it back.

```
    public static void writeThrowableToQueue(){
    final Throwable throwable;
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException("serialise");
    }catch(Throwable e){
        throwable = e;
    }


    try (ChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(file).build()) {
        final ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();
            appender.writeDocument(w -> {
                w.getValueOut().int64(System.currentTimeMillis());
                w.getValueOut().object(throwable);
            });
    }

    try (ChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(file).build()) {
        final ExcerptTailer tailer = queue.createTailer();
        tailer.readDocument(w -> {
            ValueIn in = w.getValueIn();
            long time = in.int64();
            System.out.println(in.object());
        });
    }

}
```

Writing works fine and I can see the exception there when I dump the queue.

But reading throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.clear(Collections.java:1074)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.WireMarshaller$CollectionFieldAccess.read(WireMarshaller.java:569)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.WireMarshaller.readMarshallable(WireMarshaller.java:143)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.Wires.readMarshallable(Wires.java:253)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.SerializationStrategies$5.readUsing(SerializationStrategies.java:121)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.BinaryWire$BinaryValueIn.marshallable(BinaryWire.java:2897)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.ValueIn.object(ValueIn.java:482)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.BinaryWire$BinaryValueIn.objectWithInferredType(BinaryWire.java:3158)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.ValueIn.object(ValueIn.java:435)
at queue.QueuePlayGround.lambda$writeThrowableToQueue$1(QueuePlayGround.java:44)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.readDocument(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:805)
at queue.QueuePlayGround.writeThrowableToQueue(QueuePlayGround.java:41)
at queue.QueuePlayGround.main(QueuePlayGround.java:20)
```

I've tried with other objects (Marshallables) and this works fine.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Throwable has a field which is an unmodifiable collection and whatever magic this marshaller is attempting is making an inaccurate assumption about what it can do with the field and dying. Throwable serializes just fine so presumably this is a bug. You don't really need to throw an exception to instantiate it (or populate its stack trace), though, and catching Throwable is a bad idea you should avoid.

Comment: Agreed it should serialize just fine which is why I raised the issue. Appreciate your points about Throwables - the example in the query is just to demonstrate the issue in a localized manner.

Comment: \there is definitely a bug here, investigating...

Comment: One workaround is to just use java serialization and dump the resulting byte array into your write. Somewhat clunkier but gets you around the broken custom serialization.

Comment: There is a Chronicle workaround in the example above. You can use the throwable() on the ValueIn and ValueOut(). Of course your code has to aware of when the object being written is a Throwable but I can live with that.